# BTRFS - how to replace a failed drive

Tags: linux, btrfs

I have a RAID10 BTRFS on `/dev/sda4`, `/dev/sdb4`, `/dev/sdc4`, and `/dev/sdd4`.

The `sdd` drive failed. I replaced it, and rebuilt the partition table like with `sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdd`.

I managed to mount the btrfs filesystem in its degraded state with `mount -o degraded`, but now I cannot figure out how to replace the old `/dev/sdd4` in the filesystem with the *new* `/dev/sdd4`.

When I try to delete the missing device:

```
root@sauron:~# btrfs device delete /dev/sdd4 /big1
ERROR: error removing the device '/dev/sdd4' - unable to go below four devices on raid10
```

This is the replace command I tried. It has no output, but then when I check the status, it shows it was never started:

```
btrfs replace start /dev/sdd4 /dev/sdd4 -r /big1
```

The other partitions on these disks are four-way MDRAID1 devices, which I have successfully fixed on the new drive with the `mdadm` command.

I've been scouring google for help, but nothing I have found has been helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation:

> In case of raidXX layout, you cannot go below the minimum number of the device required. So before removing a device (even the missing one) you may need to add a new one.

```
mount in degraded mode
add a new device
remove the missing device
```

See [here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices)

Comment: This did fix it.  Now I'm doing a filesystem balance.  Looks like everything's going to be fine.